# Conditional content in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am using the package moderncv. I implemented already a conditional statement in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newif\ifresume
\resumetrue %true for RESUME, false for CV
```

This allows me to set up different designs for either generation of a resume or a cv based on the same data. What I would like to do now, is to also to implement this condition in the

```
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}
```

data fields in the following sense:

```
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{(short) Description for resume}{(long) Description for CV}
```

I already tried various ideas to implement this, but none succeeded. The obvious solution would be

```
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{\ifresume
%Text for RESUME
\else
%Text for CV
\fi}
```

but that does not appear very pracicable.#

Any ideas how to solve this smoothly?

Cheers,
Mil

Comment: Have you considered using a combination of `xparse` and `expl3`? That would allow you a very simple document-level interface with very readable code-behind.  (If you go this route, I'd also recommend using `l3keys`, but that's my preference… something like `cvtext=` and `resumetext=`.)

Comment: I havn't heard about these packages before and am not completely sure what their result would be. I will look into them though. :)

Comment: Make a `\newcommand` that incorporates `\cventry` into it with 7 args.; when `\resumetrue` is in effect, it spits out all 7, when `\resumefalse` is in effect, it spits out 6.  Note that the `ifthen` package is not needed for `\newif`, and also is superseded in many ways by `etoolbox`.

Comment: I had the same idea at the same moment! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a combination of `expl3` and `xparse`:

[image: output]

Note that, since it's keyval-based markup, you can explicitly set `resume-mode` for any single item (or group of items, if you do `{ \ResumeMode[true] \CVEntry{…} \CVEntry{…} … }`).

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mil / resume } { % from `expl3`
  start        .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_start_tl,
  end          .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_end_tl,
  degree       .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_degree_tl,
  institution  .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_institution_tl,
  city         .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_city_tl,
  grade        .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_grade_tl,
  resume-text  .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_resumetext_tl,
  cv-text      .tl_set:N   = \l_mil_resume_cvtext_tl,
  resume-mode  .bool_set:N = \l_mil_resume_mode_bool
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ResumeMode { O{true} } { % from `xparse`
  \keys_set:nn { mil / resume } { resume-mode = #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \CVEntry { m } {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { mil / resume } { #1 }
  \cventry{\l_mil_resume_start_tl--\l_mil_resume_end_tl}
          {\l_mil_resume_degree_tl}
          {\l_mil_resume_institution_tl}
          {\l_mil_resume_city_tl}
          {\l_mil_resume_grade_tl}
          {
            \bool_if:NTF \l_mil_resume_mode_bool {
              \l_mil_resume_resumetext_tl
            } {
              \l_mil_resume_cvtext_tl
            }
          }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}
\name{John}{Doe}

\ResumeMode[false]

\begin{document}
\CVEntry{
  start=1993,
  end=2005,
  degree=B.\,S.,
  institution=\TeX\ StackExchange,
  city=Internet,
  grade=Grade,
  resume-text=resume text,
  cv-text=cv text,
}
\CVEntry{
  start=1993,
  end=2005,
  degree=B.\,S.,
  institution=\TeX\ StackExchange,
  city=Internet,
  grade=Grade,
  resume-text=resume text,
  cv-text=cv text,
  resume-mode=true,
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like a very promising solution Seal Allred! Its very elegant! Just a short question: I am trying to change my layout settings in dependence on \ResumeMode[false] or \ResumeMode[true], however I am not sure how to adjust the if-command: \ifResumeMode %settings for resume \else %settings for cv \fi. Do you know what the proper command is? :)

Comment: @Mil Take a look at the `\bool_if:NTF` macro there -- it takes a look at `\_mil_resume_mode_bool` and inserts `resumetext` or `cvtext` depending. Take a look at page 38 of `texdoc interface3` for a more detailed explanation, but the syntax idea is basically `\if{resume mode}{true code}{false code}`.  That is, `\bool_if:NTF \l_resume_mode_bool {true code}{false code}` or `\bool_if:NT \l_resume_mode_bool {true code}` or `\bool_if:NF \l_resume_mode_bool {false code}`.

Comment: Ah, that clears things up, thank you. I thought I understood how it works, but the implementation still doesnt work. I tried `\moderncvcolor{\bool_if:NTF \l_mil_resume_mode_bool {blue}{green}}` and `\bool_if:NTF \l_mil_resume_mode_bool {\moderncvcolor{blue}}{\moderncvcolor{green}}` but I only get "undefined control sequence.

Comment: @Mil What is it saying is undefined?  (My gut tells me to try `\exp_args:No \moderncvcolor { \bool_if:NTF ... }`)

Comment: I think your gut was right: It doesnt give any errors now. However it only works for the "true" code. ResumeMode[false] gives the same result as ResumeMode[true].

Comment: Strange... at this point, I would post a follow-up question.  Make a new post and link back to this one; hopefully we can figure out what's going on. (Remember to make a full MWE.)

Comment: I added the following command `\NewDocumentCommand \CVmode { m O{} } {\bool_if:NTF \l_mil_resume_mode_bool {#2}{#1}}` to handle what should be displayed if CV or resume.

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives me a solution. But it is still not very nice:

```
\newcommand{\Cventry}[7]{\ifresume \cventry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6} \else \cventry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7} \fi}
```